# Consider the integral $I = \int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^1 \frac{y(e^{x^2})}{x^3} dx dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate the iterated integral by first reversing the order of integration
$$\displaystyle I = \int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{y}}^1 \frac{y(e^{x^2})}{x^3} dx dy$$

Comment: Please edit the question to include the expression (properly formatted).

Answer (score 1):

First we identify the **double** integral that is being computed. The curve $x=\sqrt{y}$ is the right half of the parabola $y=x^2$. We are integrating from $x=\sqrt{y}$ to $x=1$, and then from $y=0$ to $y=1$. So we are integraing over the part of the first quadrant which is below $y=x^2$, and to the left of $x=1$. Draw a picture.

Integrate first with respect to $y$, and then with respect to $x$. So $y$ travels from $0$ to $x^2$, then $x$ travels from $0$ to $1$. We get
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \left(\int_{y=0}^{x^2}\frac{ye^{x^2}}{x^3}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$
Integrate with respect to $y$, and "plug in." We get $\frac{x^4}{2}\frac{e^{x^2}}{x^3}$, that is, $\frac{x}{2}e^{x^2}$. For the integration with respect to $x$, we can write down an antiderivative directly, or let $u=x^2$.